# Solidify from midplane

Tags: objects, faces, extrude, solidify-modifier

Is it possible to use the solidify modifier from midplane/faces, like extrude from midplane in CAD?

I have looked through both simple and complex algorithm but there does not seem an option for it.. If anyone knows it would save a lot of time in moving and scaling. The curvatures are quite complex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show your object?

Comment: I've added the image. It is the brim of the vest, but because it solidifies to one side it is not exactly in the middle of the vest anymore

Comment: Maybe ALT-E > Extrude Faces along Normals?

Comment: @JohnEason Has some potential for sure, thanks! Is it possible to do this bi-directional at once tho? Cause after extruding it to one side, it takes a hell of an effort to select all of the original faces again to extrude to the other side.. Just a lazy question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CAD and don't really know what you mean by 'extrude from midplane' so it's difficult to know what you're actually trying to achieve. Can you add an image with an indication of what you need to your question? You might get other more useful suggestions if you do.

Comment: @JohnEason Sorry, my bad. I have added the picture from CAD from what I am trying to accomplish. In direction is shows 'midplane', and the viewfinder shows the plane/face in the middle and the extrusion going both ways.

Comment: In Blender you can only extrude a face in one direction because a face has no thickness.

Comment: Just set the "Offset" to 0 instead of -1 in the modifier.

Comment: @FFeller I don't know how I completely overlooked this option but that is it! Thank you. I don't know how to make your reply the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the "Offset" to 0 instead of -1 in the modifier. –
FFeller